# how to convert this code to t-sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

i have this linq code in C#, and this working. but i want use this in stored procedure in sql server 2008. so, i want convert this to t-sql query.

```
var listComment = (from c in Conn.Comments.Where(cm => cm.Type == 1).ToList()
                   where c.AID == _id && c.PID == 0
                   let answer = Conn.Comments.Where(cm => cm.PID == c.CID).FirstOrDefault()
                   orderby c.DateSend descending
                   select new { c, answer}).ToList();
```

i can convert to this code for select c, but i can not select answer.

please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the T-SQL being sent to the server via the context Log object. You can also fire up Profiler and capture the T-SQL sent to the server.

Comment: i can not convert this code: let answer = Conn.Comments.Where(cm => cm.PID == c.CID).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: What does that have to do with how to capture the T-SQL that is generated from your query? That was your question.

Comment: i have table comment. i have select comment and your answer.

Comment: linqpad is a great tool to capture queries generated by EntityFramework and I believe Linq2Sql as well

Comment: @misterManager - Yes, indeed it is. LinqPad is one of my favorite tools and it will show the generated T-SQL for L2S.

Comment: i want use stored procedure in project no use linq to EF.

Comment: @RandyMinder: LinqPad can convert linq to t-sql?

Comment: Yes it can, very easily. The T-SQL will show in a separate tab.